# Do you need to put an expiration in a JWT?

Tags: session, redis, jwt

If I'm implementing an authentication layer in my app using a mix of JWT and Redis to store session data, do I need to include an expiring in the JWT token itself?

For example, when you login to the app, a session id is generated and added to the redis database with an expiry of 3 days. Then that session id (along with username) is used to create the JWT payload. On all auth requests, I make sure the session id from the token exists in the redis database. If it doesn't, the session has expired and I issue a new token.

Are there security issues with this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No security issues but one may argue that by including an expiry field in the JWT, the Redis layer can be made obsolete. In principle the JWT allows the application to become stateless. If your application is going to store all of its session data in Redis anyhow (because the JWT would be too large for that) one may argue that the benefit of using a JWT over a plain random session identifier is gone.

Bottom line: the `exp` field in a JWT is optional and you are free to implement another mechanism to achieve the same.

Comment: If I only include the expiration in the JWT, don't I forgo control expiring sessions forcefully? If I decide to push an update and want all sessions to be pruned, I would have to wait at least the length of the session before being sure all older JWTs are pruned no?

Comment: that is correct but you can make the expiry short and do a rolling refresh of JWTs to mitigate that

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implement your authentication/authorization layer.

Your authentication/authorization flow is *stateful*, thus expiration is very coupled with the session. I would include expiration just to let consumers of the whole JWT know when is going to expire and take actions based on this information.

There's also the *stateless* approach where there's no session identifier and there's no server storing information, but the JWT is self-descriptive, containing expiration and other data as *claims*. Since the consumer of the JWT relies in the JWT producer, and communications are secured by using a transport-level security approach like HTTPS/SSL, there's no need to maintain state but the state is the JWT itself.

One of most well-known and standarized autentication/authorization flows is [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). I would say that you should build your security layer on top of industry standards. This is good because you avoid a lot of R&D, security holes and time.